# Cassandra Prepared Statement - Binding Parameters Twice

Tags: cassandra, cql, datastax, datastax-java-driver

I have a cql query I want to preform. The cql string looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM :columnFamilyName WHERE <some_column_name> = :name AND <some_id> = :id;
```

My application has two layers of abstraction above the datastax driver. In one layer I want to bind the first two parameters and in another layer I'd like to bind the last parameter.
The problem is, if I bind the first two parameters, I get a BoundStatement to which I cannot bind another parameter. Am I missing something? Can it be done?

We're using datastax driver version 2.0.3.

Thanks,
Anatoly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to bind any number of parameters to your BoundStatement using *boundStatement.setXXXX(index,value)* as follows :

```
BoundStatement statement = new BoundStatement(query);
statement.setString(0, "value");
statement.setInt(1, 1);
statement.setDate(2, new Date());
ResultSet results = session.execute(statement);
```

The problem though is that you're trying to use a dynamic column family whose value changes with the value you want to bind.
As far as I know, this is not allowed so you should instead prepare one statement per table and then use the right bound statement.

Comment: Regarding you're last comment, can you point me to the documentation page where it's written?

Comment: Look at the answer of Olivier Michallat at the bottom of this page : https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!topic/java-driver-user/YhjJTPXkmRI
FYI, he is one of the Datastax Java driver dev.